# Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float xx.xxxx to int loses precision in excel_reader2.php on line 922

Tags: php, excel-reader

OS: Windows 11
PHP Version 8.1.6

Error Mesage:
Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 65.03846153846153 to int loses precision in C:\xampp\htdocs\sati\import\excel_reader2.php on line 922

```
public function __construct($file='',$store_extended_info=true,$outputEncoding='') {

  $this->_ole = new OLERead();
  $this->setUTFEncoder('iconv');
  if ($outputEncoding != '') { 
    $this->setOutputEncoding($outputEncoding);
  }
  for ($i=1; $i<245; $i++) {
    $name = strtolower(( (($i-1)/26>=1)?chr(($i-1)/26+64):'') . chr(($i-1)%26+65));  //line 922
    $this->colnames[$name] = $i;
    $this->colindexes[$i] = $name;
  }
  $this->store_extended_info = $store_extended_info;
  if ($file!="") {
    $this->read($file);
  }
}
```

**Anyone have ideia to fix the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [it's deprecated](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string)

You should cast your calculations to ints when passing into `chr()`:

```php
strtolower(
    (
        ($i-1)/26>=1
            ? chr((int) ($i-1)/26+64)
            : ''
    )
    . chr((int) ($i-1)%26+65)
)
```

Comment: I changed the code, but continuos the same mesage.

Comment: You need to add some more brackets: `chr((int) (($i-1)/26+64))` and `chr((int) (($i-1)%26+65))`

Comment: Thanks! Now it worked without error.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed function**

```
/**
* Constructor
*
* Some basic initialisation
*/
//function Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($file='',$store_extended_info=true,$outputEncoding='') { // DEPRECATED EDITED IN 06-2020
    public function __construct($file='',$store_extended_info=true,$outputEncoding='') {    
        $this->_ole = new OLERead();
        $this->setUTFEncoder('iconv');
        if ($outputEncoding != '') { 
            $this->setOutputEncoding($outputEncoding);
        }
        for ($i=1; $i<245; $i++) {
            //$name = strtolower(( (($i-1)/26>=1)?chr(($i-1)/26+64):'') . chr(($i-1)%26+65)); // DEPRECATED EDITED IN 07-2022
            $name = strtolower(( (($i-1)/26>=1)? chr((int) (($i-1)/26+64)) :'') . chr((int) (($i-1)%26+65)) );
            $this->colnames[$name] = $i;
            $this->colindexes[$i] = $name;
        }
        $this->store_extended_info = $store_extended_info;
        if ($file!="") {
            $this->read($file);
        }
    }
```